# Help me convert .NET 1.1 Xml validation code to .NET 2.0 please

Tags: c#, deprecated, asp.net-1.1, xml-validation

It would be fantastic if you could help me rid of these warnings below.
I have not been able to find a good document. Since the warnings are concentrated in just the `private void ValidateConfiguration( XmlNode section )` section, hopefully this is not terribly hard to answer, if you have encountered this before.

***Thanks!***

```
'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException.ConfigurationException(string)' is obsolete: 'This class is obsolete, to create a new exception create a System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException'   

'System.Xml.XmlValidatingReader' is obsolete: 'Use XmlReader created by XmlReader.Create() method using appropriate XmlReaderSettings instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'
```

---

```
private void ValidateConfiguration( XmlNode section )
{                
    // throw if there is no configuration node.
    if( null == section )
    {
        throw new ConfigurationException("The configuration section passed within the ... class was null ... there must be a configuration file defined.", section );
    }
    //Validate the document using a schema
    XmlValidatingReader vreader = new XmlValidatingReader( new XmlTextReader( new StringReader( section.OuterXml ) ) );
    //  open stream on Resources; the XSD is set as an "embedded resource" so Resource can open a stream on it
    using (Stream xsdFile = XYZ.GetStream("ABC.xsd"))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xsdFile))
    {
        vreader.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
        vreader.Schemas.Add(XmlSchema.Read(new XmlTextReader(sr), null));
        vreader.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        // Validate the document
        while (vreader.Read()) { }

        if (!_isValidDocument)
        {
            _schemaErrors = _sb.ToString();
            throw new ConfigurationException("XML Document not valid");
        }
    }
}

// Does not cause warnings.
private void ValidationCallBack( object sender, ValidationEventArgs args )
{
    //  check what KIND of problem the schema validation reader has;
    //  on FX 1.0, it gives a warning for "<xs:any...skip" sections.  Don't worry about those, only set validation false
    //  for real errors
    if( args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error )
    {
        _isValidDocument = false;
        _sb.Append( args.Message + Environment.NewLine );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the changes suggested in the warnings?  If so, did you have any problems?

Comment: I think he's looking for how to make those changes. The link provided in the warning isn't that useful.

Comment: You do not need to convert from C# 1.1 to C# 2.0 (especially since there's no such thing as C# 1.1). You need to convert from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace
    
    `throw new ConfigurationException(....)`
    
    with

   `throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(....)`
2. Replace  `XmlValidatingReader vreader = new XmlValidatingReader(...)`
   with

---

```
var vreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(section.OuterXml), 
                               new XmlReaderSettings
                               {
                                  ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
                               });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's telling you to use the `XmlReaderSettings` instead of the `XmlValidatingReader`, which was deprecated.

Personally I'm not going to do the conversion, I think that you actually doing that will be good for your coding development, so here is some resources:

Look at the overloads of the `XmlReader.Create()` method, specifically [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162474.aspx).

Then have a look at the different properties associated with the `XmlReaderSettings` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings_members.aspx

Give it a try, see what happens and if your still having problems, ask another question :)

HTH